# firebase function fails with error gserviceaccount.com:signBlob failed, reason: Client network socket disc

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

i am trying to create a firebase cloud function which gets download url of an image which is valid for a long time. My code that throws error is as follows:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

await admin.storage().bucket('gs://myproject.appspot.com').file(filePath).getSignedUrl({
          action: 'read',
          expires: '03-09-2491'
        })
```

it looks like my firebase-admin service account does not have permission to create access key. i am not sure how to grant it? as this code works in my local machine when i use a json file to generate the credentials.

any pointers on how to resolve this will be appreciated?

thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1):

Check the roles assigned to your App Engine default service account ==> `[projectID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

By default this includes the role of `project/editor`, you need add the role  `Cloud Functions Service Agent` to the service account, this role includes the permission necessary to generate signed a URL `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob`

Please check the permissions/roles of the service account within your bucket, `project/editor` is enough but if you are using another account you need to assign the role `Legacy Bucket Reader`

This is a sample code that you can adjust for your use case

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp()

exports.gensigned = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    var filePath="myfile.html"

    var url = await admin.storage().bucket('gs://myproject').file(filePath).getSignedUrl({
          action: 'read',
          expires: '03-09-2491'
        })

    console.log(url)


    res.json({ "url": url});
    });
```